# Find a $4$ by $4$ permutation $\hat{P}$ with $\hat{P} \neq I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working through Intro. to Linear Algebra by Strang (4th edition). And have come across an answer/solution pair that doesn't make sense to me.

The questions is

Find a $4$ by $4$ permutation $\hat{P}$ with $\hat{P} \neq I$.

The solution given is:

Let $\hat{P}$ be the block diagonal matrix with $1$ and $P$ on the diagonal: $\hat{P} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&P\end{bmatrix}$. Since $P^3 = I$, also $\hat{P}^3=I$. So $\hat{P}^4 = \hat{P} \neq I$.

I believe $P=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

I have a few questions about this solution/problem:

(1) How is $\hat{P}$ even considered to be $4$ by $4$?

(2) How are the dimensions of $\hat{P}$ supposed to be interpreted? I am assuming the $1$'s and $0$'s in $\hat{P}$ are supposed to be $3$ by $3$ matrices of $1$'s and $0$'s and not scalars? Otherwise, how would we perform exponentiation on $\hat{P}$?

If anyone could provide clarity on this question/answer pair beyond the two questions above, that would also be appreciated. I am new to linear algebra so please keep that in mind.

Comment: It's a **block matrix** containing a column $(1,0,0,0)$, three $0$'s above $P$ and $P$ itself which is $3 \times 3$. Are you still confused?

Comment: Are you sure the question is "find a 4 by 4 permutation $\hat P$ with $\hat P \ne I$"? It seems weird to me to have a hat on $P$ for no apparent reason. Also, if the goal is just to create a non-identity permutation why go through all of this work? Secondly, why does $P^3 = I$? Is this an assumption? Is $P$ defined somewhere?

Comment: @stressed-out No, I am not confused if that is the case... so is this just standard notation? We assume that the other values expand to fill the row and column counts that we infer from $P$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn: I believe the author (Gilbert Strang, I assume) has put a hat on $P$ to distinguish it with the three by three matrix. But I don't understand why he made it so complicated. It's a very simple problem. ClownInTheMoon: Yes, it's a commonly used notation for block matrices as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\hat{P}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\0 & 0&0&1\\ 0 & 1&0&0\\0 &0&1&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & P \end{bmatrix}$

Hence it is a $4$ by $4$ matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & P \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & P^n \end{bmatrix}$$